# 2 UIButton with dynamic text and font size

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I am using 2 `UIButton` in same y position. The one on the left is shorter in text than the one on the right:

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdaQZ.png)

I am adding

```
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
```

for each button. `The problem is that one button font size get smaller than the other`. For example, they are both with font size 18, one might get 12 and the other will stay 18. I want them both to be 15 (the larger possible keeping both texts visible)

The text inserted to the buttons changes so i can't use aspect ratio.
Also, i don't want to use the font of the button with the smaller text because the difference is sometimes to high.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking... You state: *"I'm setting the font to scale down, but I don't want to use the smaller text."* -- So - what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it programmatically with stack view, declare your buttons under your controller class:

```
let myButton: UIButton = {
    let b = UIButton()
    b.backgroundColor = .white
    b.setTitle("Short button", for: .normal)
    b.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    b.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .regular)
    b.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    b.clipsToBounds = true
    b.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    b.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return b
}()

let myButton2: UIButton = {
    let b = UIButton()
    b.backgroundColor = .white
    b.setTitle("Much Much Much longer button", for: .normal)
    b.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    b.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .regular)
    b.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    b.clipsToBounds = true
    b.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    b.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return b
}()
```

Now in viewDidLoad set stackView and constraints (I set 6 for space, but you can set your prefer space, look at the comment to do it):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [myButton, myButton2])
    stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
    stackView.spacing = 6 // change space betwenn buttons
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
}
```

This is the result shortButton/shortButton and shortButton/longerButton, the width of the buttons changes dynamically according to the text:

[image]